# object typesafe is not a member of package

Tags: scala, heroku

I am currently trying to build and deploy a simple scala application on heroku. I am following the tutorial on the heroku website for Scala: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala

However I keep getting the following error when I execute **sbt clean compile stage**:
[image: Screenshot error]

My build.sbt file is as follows:

```
import com.typesafe.startscript.StartScriptPlugin

seq(StartScriptPlugin.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)

name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

resolvers += "twitter-repo" at "http://maven.twttr.com"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.twitter" % "finagle-core" % "1.9.0", "com.twitter" % "finagle-http" % "1.9.0")
```

I have a project/build.sbt file as well as follows:

```
resolvers += "twitter-repo" at "http://maven.twttr.com"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.twitter" % "finagle-core" % "1.9.0", "com.twitter" % "finagle-http" % "1.9.0")
```

My project/build.properties file is as follows:

```
sbt.version=0.12.0
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?, help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `project/build.sbt` wrong: it should be

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")
```

according to the tutorial. More generally, try reading [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/).

Comment: That sorted it. Thank you very much Alexey.